# Nested state handling in SolidJS components with Immer's "produce"

Tags: typescript, solid-js, immer.js

I have a SolidJS application, and I'm storing a large JSON object that nests other objects. I'm using Immer to generate patches for undo and redo actions. (well, technically I'm storing a class with nested classes several layers deep, but Immer handles them just fine, so this seems like a trivial detail.)

I'd like to be able to pass a subset of that big object to components, say `bigObject.someProp[0]`, and allow the component to modify and access that instead of having to access `bigObject` directly. Something like this:

```
function createImmerSignal<T>(value: T) {
  const [get, set] = createSignal(value);

  function newSet(callback: (draft: Draft<T>) => void) {
    const newVal = produce(get(), callback, (redo, undo) => {
      // Undo and redo logic, would modify some context variable
    });
    set(newVal as Exclude<T, Function>);
  }

  // createNested is what I'm looking to implement
  return [get, newSet, createNested];
}

type Company = {
  name: string;
  developers: {
    name: string;
    someOtherProp: string;
  }[];
};

function CompOne(prop: { origCompany: Company }) {
  const [company, setCompany, createNested] = createImmerSignal<Company>(origCompany);

  // I'm not sure what a good syntax for this would be, or how to even get this functional. This syntax is what I've come up with:
  const dev = createNested(company => company.developers[0]);

  return <>
    <CompTwo dev={dev} />
  </>
}

function CompTwo(props) {
  // createNested can be used indefinitely
  const [dev, setDev, createNested] = props.dev;

  setDev(draft => {
    // This would update company.developers[0].someProp
    draft.name = 'Darles Nemeni';
  });

  return <></>;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to implement this, especially in a way that would respect types. I've tried using functions (`company => company.developers[0]`) to select the subset of `company`:

```
function newNested<U>(sel: (orig: T | Draft<T>) => U) {
  return (fn: (draft: Draft<U>) => void) => set(
    produce(get(), draft => {
      // vvvvvvv This does not work, as you cannot assign like that
      sel(draft) = produce(sel(draft), draft => fn(draft))
    }) as Exclude<T, Function>
  )
}


newNested(company => company.developers[0])
```

However, I cannot assign a value to `sel(draft)`, unless I access a property on the parent, and I don't believe there's a clean way to do that.

My only idea for fixing that above (and I'm not sure if it's a good idea or would work) would be to somehow use a proxy to detect which properties are being accessed and recursively create a string of accessors to then use on `draft`, but that hardly seems efficient or clean.

To reiterate my question: What would be the best and cleanest way of designing this?

---

Semi-related question: I'm struggling to describe this problem, so if anyone has a better title, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Best course of action is getting rid of `createImmerSignal` and use a store: https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#store-utilities. Store provides Immer like API and uses a Proxy to rewire interactions to provide reactivity. It has many utilities to help you interact with the stored value and since store produces a reactive value, you can derive a subset of it directly without breaking a sweat.

If you insist on creating your own store then you can take a look at its implementation to get started.

Comment: The whole reason I'm using Immer is to generate the undo/redo patches, and I don't know of any way to do that with stores. I'm also worried that Immer won't be able to generate proper root-level patches if I access some lower-level property with a store.

Comment: If you are not comfortable enough with solid's reactivity, it will be much harder for you to implement Immer like API. Store is the easiest course of action here. Take a look at the API, it is not that complex. Implementing undo/redo should not be that complicated, use an effect to watch the store and push the state into a stack whenever there is a change. I remember some libraries providing undo/redo functionality, check solid primitives history. There are others too.

Comment: e.g. https://primitives.solidjs.community/package/history

Comment: The state itself is very large, it wouldn't be a good idea to push the entire thing to a history stack.

I saw that package when looking for other solutions previously, but it stores the entire state.

Comment: How large is your file, if it is few MBs, you won't have any issues with a stack but if we are talking about 100s of MBs or GBs, patching would be better alternative, either way store is your best option and you said your are looking for Immer like API and store already implements that and it has full of utilities to run patch updates on a complex object. You can derive a subset of the state using a function.That is all I can say.

Comment: The size would vary a lot. In some cases, around 70MB and 5MB for two examples respectively. I'd like to go the route of patching, it seems a lot better than storing so much in memory.